# unable to show alert message based on data fetched from php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, authentication

code from action.php

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]))  
 {  
      $query = "  
      SELECT * FROM Admin 
      WHERE Username = '".$_POST["username"]."'  
      AND Password = '".$_POST["password"]."'  
      ";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
      {  
           $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];  
           echo 'Yes';  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           echo 'No';  
      }  
 }  
 if(isset($_POST["action"]))  
 {  
      unset($_SESSION["username"]);  
 }
```

code from index.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#login_button').click(function(){  
           var username = $('#username').val();  
           var password = $('#password').val();  
           if(username != '' && password != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"action.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data: {username:username, password:password},  

                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          //alert(data);  
                          if(data == 'No')  
                          {  
                               alert("Wrong Data");  
                          }  
                          else  
                          {  
                               $('#loginModal').hide();  
                               location.reload();  
                          }  
                     }  
                });  
           }
```

In the above index.php code always else part is executed. so I believe the data is not received from action.php code But `$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];` part of the code in action.php code is executed.

so my question is why 'Yes' or 'No' is not sent as it is expected.

any kind of help will be greatly appreciated;

Comment: What does `alert(data)` show? Have you tried making sure there isn't extra white space created from your php script? ie using [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) on `data`

Comment: There were no extra white spaces @Patrick

Comment: If trim() made it work, then there was. As that is what trim does, removes leading / trailing white spaces

Comment: @PatrickEvans as the above code in action.php shows, there are no whitespaces. But when i tried this: alert('('+data+')');  it prints (No ). i.e, there is extra space. I don't understand why this behaviour.

Comment: White space can be any space, that includes new lines. This usually happens because you have some white space outside of the php tags `<?php ?>` which might not be readily visible. Always make sure there is no white space before or after those tags, or make sure to use trim() where appropriate

Comment: @PatrickEvans, will keep in mind your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: yeah, in my action.php code, after  ?> at the very last line extra whitespace was there.

Answer (score 0):

use 'datas' in the alert.. You misspelled them

Comment: @user2486 sorry that was the mistake, i edited my question. still doesn't work

Comment: Check in the console if there are any errors, if no check if the id of button is the same

Comment: Check if  data: {"username":username, "password":password} fixes the issue

Comment: what is the result of `alert(data)` or `console.log(data)`?

Comment: everything is fine just the data is not sent properly. If i put the alert part in else, it shows the alert message.

Comment: @am05mhz i have a login window popped up, how can i check the output of console.log(data)

Comment: is there a session_start() in action.php?

Comment: @BlessonChristy it is there.

Comment: right click anywhere on the page in your browser, click inspect element, then find the console in the window that shows up, or search web console in google

Comment: @am05mhz, alert data does show 'No', But then why alert("Wrong data") doesn't work?

Comment: then try patrick's suggestion `if (data.trim() == 'No')`, also make sure to check the same-case (uppercase / lowercase)

Comment: did you check, any error message show in your console? @MONU KUMAR

Comment: @BlessonChristy, I checked the value of data using alert(data) it shows 'No'. But then why if part is not executed?

Comment: @MONUKUMAR, use data.trim() inside if

Comment: data.trim() does work. Thank you guys for your awesome support.

Comment: By the way any suggestion why it didn't work without trim()

Comment: action.php or some other included config files may had line breaks or extra spaces (most probably before php tag)

Comment: Mark as answer if helped